# Change default Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I had to import a backup PST file in Outlook recently but it duplicated all my folders. For mails and contacts no real problem, just moved them all over but for calendars I can't seem to do that. I now have a Calendar folder (default, empty) and a Calendar1 folder (which contains all my appointments).

How can I make Calendar1 the default (and rename it) or can I move everything over?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to get around this. You can open the calendar in list view (Outlook 2010: Calendar > View > Change View > List). Then you can select all appointments and move them to another calendar.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2010, go to File > Account Settings, then select the Data Files tab, choose the email address you want to be the default, and click on "Set as Default".

Answer (score -1):

For Outlook 2007, try File > Data File Management > Data Files tab, highlight the one you want to use, and choose 'set as default' (which is just above the list of data files).

For Outlook 2010, try File > Account Settings > Account Settings > Data File Tab.

Comment: I'm not having two data files. I'm having 2 calendar folders in 1 datafile and the wrong one is the default one...

Comment: Cornbread Ninja, since there is no such path in Outlook (File> Data File Management) how do you get to this illusive folder? It would be a beautiful thing, but it doesn't exist!

Comment: @pcancva there is in Outlook 2007.